# Testing Google Endpoint. http://localhost:8080/ Vs http://localhost:8080//_ah/api/explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new about the using of Google Endpoint. I have imported in Eclipse EE the Helloworld sample from Google Java sample project. I did all the setup and i beging the test. If I type `localhost:8080` on my Chrome Browser, I see the front end, and it's ok. But if I type

```
http://localhost:8080//_ah/api/explorer
```

for test the REST API, Chrome (even Explorer) redirect the address to:

```
http://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/
```

And from here, I can test my REST API without problem. I am not expert of all the configuration that i can do on the `web.xml` file, `pom.xml` file, etc, but I would like to test my backend REST API without to be connected on internet. Is it possible to test and deploy the backend REST API offline on my local server, I mean, without to connect to Google site? I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: You should format your question to gain attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to call endpoint method without internet connection if it's OAuth2 protected. Every method with `User` param is using auth token which must be validated with OAuth2 server.

To call not protected endpoint method you can use `curl` or `wget` utilities on Linux. I'm sure you will find corresponding tools for Windows.

When you call a method using API Explorer the displayed header field contains information about the request. This data will be useful to call the methods on your own. With curl it will not be as easy as using API Explorer but here are examples:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "test",
        path = "test",
        httpMethod = HttpMethods.GET
)
public StringResult getTest(@Nullable @Named("param") String param) {
    return new StringResult("not protected method: " + param);
}
```

Using API Explorer:

Header

```
GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/app/v1/test
```

Response

```
200 OK

{
 "value": "not protected method: null"
}
```

Now using `curl` on terminal

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/app/v1/test
```

Response

```
{
  "value" : "not protected method: null"
}
```

Using any browser to test non protected GET methods

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/app/v1/test?param=testParam
```

Response displayed in the browser

```
{
  "value" : "not protected method: testParam"
}
```

Comment: thank for your replay. Now, for be clear, if i would like to test my REST API without internet connection and using only Eclipse and Maven, without Oath2, is it possible?. Why everytime i type:localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer, the browser redirect me tohttp://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api#p/? Recently i used Spring and with Spring is possible to develop my RESTful API in local but without it it's seem not possible.

Comment: Neither Eclipse nor Maven are HTTP clients so you cannot test any API using these tools. You can also use your browser to test non protected GET methods. Please check the updated answer.